# Journal contet search shows only articles from one site after deploying hook

Tags: java, jsp, liferay

I need to sort results of journal_content_search (default search for journal articles) by modify date. So I wrote simple hook, adding these lines to `html/portlet/journal_content_search/search.jsp`

```
Sort[] sorts = new Sort[] {new Sort(Field.MODIFIED_DATE, true)};
searchContext.setSorts(sorts);
```

(+ I imported `com.liferay.portal.kernel.search.Sort` in init.jsp file).

Sorting seems to work fine, but after deploying this hook searching shows only journal articles from one site defined in Liferay! Before deploy it searched through all sites, and now only one.
Any ideas how to change it / other proper way to sort journal articles serach results by date?

Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing that the articles shown are for the site where the portlet is deployed. If that is the case then you need to set the scope of the portlet to the global scope by using its id.
This can be done through the ServiceContext object like this

```
serviceContext.setScopeGroupId(givenGroupId);
```

This i hope should do the trick!